Movie about kids entering an old mansion and finding a bottle/lamp
I can't remember clearly about this movie... Maybe it was a 80's or early 90's movie, I can't remember since the last time I watched it was on TV and I was probably 7 or 8.
There was these kids inside of a old, abandoned, mansion, and they find an bottle/lamp and when they open it they accidentally release a monster/demon. The lid of the bottle/lamp was a golden spider-like thing with an human head and it was alive (talking and walking). The monster/demon starts chasing then around the mansion. And if I recall correctly there was a kid's first kiss scene somewhere in this movie.

Looks like Demon in a Bottle (1996). 

Teenagers find a lost treasure buried by a 18th century pirate. They
  accidentally release the monster who lives inside a bottle.

They actually find the bottle in an underground cave/tunnel thing that leads to the old mansion after the boy drops something of the girls down a grate that leads there.
Here's the human-head spider bottle stopper:

Video of the full film on YouTube (you can see the moving bottle stopper scene at about 20:30): 


